# "unexpected EOF" when Docker image is downloaded

Tags: docker

I got:

```
unexpected EOF
```

when I downloaded the Docker image:

```
$ sudo nvidia-docker pull hub.baidubce.com/paddlepaddle/deep_speech_fluid:latest-gpu
```

May I ask how to fix it? For a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677592/docker-pull-unexpected-eof), @DavidMaze and @NataliaPakhol mentioned a way: "don't apt-get install build-essential". May I have more details? Thank you!

Comment: Do you get this error every time, or is it intermittent?

Comment: I get it every time when I run the above command. Thanks.

Comment: Anybody has any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how you can fix it on your end. My suggestions are 1) find a different image or 2) email the image authors and ask them to fix it.