# Docker pull fails with unexpected EOF

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to pull an image from a private registry but it fails with unexpected EOF.

```
be8ec4e48d7f: Already exists 
33b8b485aff0: Already exists 
d887158cc58c: Already exists 
05895bb28c18: Already exists 
3717254b824f: Already exists 
5d1752e32f1f: Already exists 
98554cf2e2ec: Already exists 
3a83ccd2f4ee: Already exists 
c793dcd65f37: Already exists 
c4412ad3121f: Already exists 
eba3bc56bff9: Already exists 
2b1b6e815dce: Already exists 
dda735bf3557: Already exists 
dbece9223ffc: Already exists 
49533680b25f: Already exists 
8d332721c923: Already exists 
d40c3e8ecbdb: Already exists 
75f43ec617dd: Already exists 
225f75c25e6b: Already exists 
81811c4b9e22: Already exists 
409197acab0f: Already exists 
9b5199518afc: Already exists 
b7040ab58553: Already exists 
b6e55490ca80: Already exists 
e04c7210075d: Already exists 
68db66ab7dda: Already exists 
bbe68713195e: Already exists 
1d7c9599b03c: Already exists 
c7472ba4bdbd: Already exists 
3c4082628c2e: Already exists 
50f7a489c209: Already exists 
aaf98f685aa2: Already exists 
8cf31fcd419c: Already exists 
a80092fe6016: Already exists 
9d90bdef5603: Already exists 
9d13d2b62b19: Already exists 
cab2bcedcfdf: Already exists 
41670cbb355b: Already exists 
4036f94db6f4: Retrying in 19 seconds 
42f95b51f0f7: Download complete 
91f3ac158888: Download complete 
df09d420f619: Download complete 
7ca46f747969: Download complete 
34e5e5eb8b2f: Download complete 
ce8b1ad11171: Download complete 
4b124d6694bd: Download complete 
a71b50d0f70c: Download complete 
237b8823183b: Download complete 
4036f94db6f4: Downloading  12.41MB/12.41MB
64858da6aaea: Download complete 
3e88dcb59e3e: Download complete 
aa92021cb41d: Download complete 
0569c05fcc65: Download complete 
63ee9c05e34b: Download complete 
48ac0999fcdb: Download complete 
e10d1975849c: Download complete 
611db2146c6f: Download complete 
7ad4e600c6c6: Download complete 
4261ad6f88e3: Download complete 
c20e2f82fd11: Download complete 
49f62c0b1913: Download complete 
cb37060da14d: Download complete 
f19eda2c4fb2: Download complete 
e600fca97576: Download complete 
508947b05054: Download complete 
652c4860c2f3: Download complete 
358d27eb7aaa: Download complete 
27cfd1cb1501: Download complete 
673d626b28c0: Download complete 
20d0b16ebf52: Download complete 
0cfff8a600f6: Download complete 
00065e08cdfc: Download complete 
bd51e67b9159: Download complete 
7e8e6548bdec: Download complete 
1dea31859db5: Download complete 
f058efbc49a4: Download complete 
3e10bb0abdd8: Download complete 
617d42f04950: Download complete 
798390048c18: Download complete 
2b389764a032: Download complete 
002f5c6ccc90: Download complete 
unexpected EOF
```

I've tried deleting the layer like suggested here [Docker pull “unexpected EOF”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677592/docker-pull-unexpected-eof) but the same error persists even I build the image with a new tag and **--no-cache**.

My workflow is the following:

- Image is built using Jenkins.
- Image is pushed to private Docker registry.
- Image is pulled in Kubernetes node.

How can I further debug this? Or forcefully delete the layer, and images that depend on it.

Comment: Which Kubernetes Network Provider are you using? Flannel, Calico, Canal? ... Might be related to the [MTU size](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/mtu)

Answer (score 2):

I had an image I [couldn't pull](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/e10ae5961d9f991bf1a556623a5717f2):

```
$ docker pull registry.com/IMAGE:TAG
TAG: Pulling from IMAGE
97518928ae5f: Already exists
784cd1fd612b: Pull complete
0ec5d186b713: Pull complete
98dc27ad6276: Pull complete
94d536c3c847: Downloading [===============================================>   ]  116.2MB/123.2MB
56a018b1cd83: Download complete
89370282bef7: Download complete
eaf17779ae5d: Downloading [==================================================>]   2.59MB/2.59MB
e031dab02d72: Download complete
unexpected EOF
```

That's the way it looked like at the end. While pulling the image it looked like so:

```
TAG: Pulling from IMAGE
97518928ae5f: Already exists
784cd1fd612b: Downloading [========>                                          ]  6.127MB/34.81MB
0ec5d186b713: Download complete
98dc27ad6276: Download complete
94d536c3c847: Downloading [>                                                  ]  540.2kB/123.2MB
56a018b1cd83: Download complete
89370282bef7: Download complete
eaf17779ae5d: Retrying in 4 seconds
e031dab02d72: Waiting
```

As such, `eaf17779ae5d` is the culprit. Let's find out the full hash:

```
$ curl -sSL https://registry.com/v2/IMAGE/manifests/TAG | jq -r '.fsLayers[] | .blobSum'
...
sha256:e031dab02d727ce644ab4ea42a26e0f1661c01049a2197b9d58e22c44fecb03d
sha256:eaf17779ae5dc4e74e2aba3dcefc629f5b5717adb20facc93c6e726664637aca
...
```

And try to confirm if we can download it:

```
$ curl -sSLv https://registry.com/v2/IMAGE/blobs/sha256:eaf17779ae5dc4e74e2aba3dcefc629f5b5717adb20facc93c6e726664637aca -o /dev/null
...
> GET /v2/IMAGE/blobs/sha256:eaf17779ae5dc4e74e2aba3dcefc629f5b5717adb20facc93c6e726664637aca HTTP/2
> Host: registry.com
> authorization: Basic ...
> user-agent: curl/7.79.1
> accept: */*
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 250)!
} [5 bytes data]
* HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
* stopped the pause stream!
* Connection #0 to host registry.com left intact
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

$ ssh root@registry.com docker exec REGISTRY_CONTAINER_ID ls /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/ea/eaf17779ae5dc4e74e2aba3dcefc629f5b5717adb20facc93c6e726664637aca
ls: /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/ea/eaf17779ae5dc4e74e2aba3dcefc629f5b5717adb20facc93c6e726664637aca: No such file or directory
```

We can't, as such let's delete the layer:

```
$ curl -sS -X DELETE https://registry.com/v2/IMAGE/blobs/sha256:eaf17779ae5dc4e74e2aba3dcefc629f5b5717adb20facc93c6e726664637aca
```

Then push the image again:

```
$ docker push registry.com/IMAGE:TAG
The push refers to repository [registry.com/IMAGE]
9be3d32c4bdc: Preparing
a17a1099bdbb: Preparing
896990f929fd: Preparing
74cfeaa3d1d8: Preparing
dd2b13d45ffc: Preparing
ff64ee97d76a: Preparing
480f61641fa1: Preparing
b3eaed7a085d: Preparing
1a058d5342cc: Preparing
ff64ee97d76a: Waiting
b3eaed7a085d: Waiting
480f61641fa1: Waiting
1a058d5342cc: Waiting
896990f929fd: Layer already exists
dd2b13d45ffc: Layer already exists
74cfeaa3d1d8: Layer already exists
9be3d32c4bdc: Layer already exists
480f61641fa1: Layer already exists
1a058d5342cc: Layer already exists
ff64ee97d76a: Layer already exists
b3eaed7a085d: Layer already exists
a17a1099bdbb: Pushed
TAG: digest: sha256:5b784cb8080660d7af7222a6b5b0630faa6942b39f0c533354500e946bf92c7c size: 2201
```

Do note the `a17a1099bdbb: Pushed` line. It means that the layer was uploaded (pushed). And also do note that the hashes differ (the local one and the one from the registry). During `pull` it displays registry hashes, during `push` local hashes. The local hash may be just a random string, the remote hash is most likely a hash of the data. Or maybe they hash different things or differently. To find out what corresponds to what you can obtain a manifest by a digest:

```
$ curl -sS https://registry.com/v2/IMAGE/manifests/sha256:5b784cb8080660d7af7222a6b5b0630faa6942b39f0c533354500e946bf92c7c | jq
{
  ...
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 7810,
    "digest": "sha256:2b71efc18e8f74f9c9ae1a83f5d2a04b09e42e6a4e3a67e381ff68fea1b9a964"
  },
  "layers": [
    ...
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 2590453,
      "digest": "sha256:eaf17779ae5dc4e74e2aba3dcefc629f5b5717adb20facc93c6e726664637aca"
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 553,
      "digest": "sha256:e031dab02d727ce644ab4ea42a26e0f1661c01049a2197b9d58e22c44fecb03d"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then obtain the config (see `.config.digest` in the output of the previous command):

```
$ curl -sS https://registry.com/v2/IMAGE/blobs/sha256:2b71efc18e8f74f9c9ae1a83f5d2a04b09e42e6a4e3a67e381ff68fea1b9a964 | jq
{
  ...
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      ...
      "sha256:a17a1099bdbb31acadd8c8ef1da7ab734e14405ed3072383a1699708af512de4",
      "sha256:9be3d32c4bdc87b8ee61ffc775f050bea4fbaf8a32ef4ddb6f6e881a92a0c4a3"
    ]
  }
}
```

`sha256:eaf17779ae5dc4e74e2aba3dcefc629f5b5717adb20facc93c6e726664637aca` is second to last, and so is `sha256:a17a1099bdbb31acadd8c8ef1da7ab734e14405ed3072383a1699708af512de4`. That's the match.

Anyways, if you delete just one layer, there should be only one "pushed" line.

Let's confirm if it works:

```
$ docker pull registry.com/IMAGE:TAG
TAG: Pulling from IMAGE
97518928ae5f: Already exists
784cd1fd612b: Pull complete
0ec5d186b713: Pull complete
98dc27ad6276: Pull complete
94d536c3c847: Pull complete
56a018b1cd83: Pull complete
89370282bef7: Pull complete
eaf17779ae5d: Pull complete
e031dab02d72: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:5b784cb8080660d7af7222a6b5b0630faa6942b39f0c533354500e946bf92c7c
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.com/IMAGE:TAG
registry.com/IMAGE:TAG
```

All done. And although my answer basically repeats the one you referenced, I believe I provided more details, and here are a couple of links just in case:

[Missing image layer in a docker registry](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/e10ae5961d9f991bf1a556623a5717f2) 
[Examining images and docker registry](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/c4eb4a900ee2f10e2568c96bacf0f9fd)

Also, if it doesn't help, you might want to run garbage collection:

```
$ docker exec REGISTRY_CONTAINER_ID registry garbage-collect -m /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

Comment: You'll probably want to add "--delete-untagged" to the garbage-collect command.  Also, you'll want to restart the registry afterwards.  After that, try re-pushing the image to the registry.  You'll likely notice that one or two layers will be pushed as new.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem and resolved it by:

1. Re-creating registry container (re-start might have been enough)
2. Re-pushing image to registry

Interestingly, after re-creating the registry I got a different error ["Unknown blob"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599288/docker-error-unknown-blob) which turned out to mean a layer was missing. So a re-push solved the issue.