# Docker unexpected EOF while pulling and image from private registry

Tags: docker-registry

I have an image in a registry, I have pulled the image multiple times with success. Today however, when I tried to pull it
`docker pull REPO_IP:5000/IMAGE:TAG`

I got an the following issue:

```
docker pull REPO_IP:5000/IMAGE:TAG
prod: Pulling from IMAGE
4bbfd2c87b75: Pull complete 
d2e110be24e1: Pull complete 
889a7173dcfe: Pull complete 
16d3b8690ce0: Pull complete 
c1a1d1cdfbc8: Pull complete 
08fdf4328628: Pull complete 
1ba5f9610307: Pull complete 
25f1dccdb63e: Pull complete 
f0c94b4d71f0: Downloading  1.988GB/1.988GB
8a5d3ae88f94: Download complete 
6c3e2a76e68b: Download complete 
d619e3aae6ca: Download complete 
7db1cfbc4b51: Download complete 
a7ca888c4eeb: Download complete 
dffe5ff1af51: Download complete 
b1ef96f04c6f: Download complete 
unexpected EOF
```

layer `f0c94b4d71f0` keeps retrying for 5 times then after all other layers finish downloading I get an `unexpected EOF`.

I tried deleting the layer as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043198/docker-pull-fails-with-unexpected-eof), then re-uploaded the image which uploaded the deleted layer with success, but I still faced the issue again when I tried to pull it.

I even deleted the registry container, then spawned a new one and mounted the old volume (which contains my images) to the new container but it did not help.

journalctl shows the following:

```
15 11:37:15 USER dockerd[204830]: time="2023-08-15T11:37:15.317498218+03:00" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://REPO_IP:5000/v2/\": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"
15 11:37:15 USER dockerd[204830]: time="2023-08-15T11:37:15.317515791+03:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://REPO_IP:5000/v2/\": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"
15 11:37:15 USER dockerd[204830]: time="2023-08-15T11:37:15.722908459+03:00" level=info msg="Download failed, retrying (1/5): unexpected EOF"
```

I have the REPO_IP added as a unsecure registry in `/etc/docker/daemon.josn`

Comment: Looks like the registry is failing on a rather large layer (2GB is a limit on some systems). Push a smaller image or try a different registry server.

Comment: It's not the first time I pulled the image from this registry, I even reduced the --max-concurrent-downloads for dockerd to 1, I created a temporary registry, re-tagged the image, pushed and pulled it with success, but that does not solve the issue for me and I don't want to completely reset the registry.