# I had my Docker Desktop installed but an error occurred when I run "docker-compose up"

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, budibase

I'm running Docker Desktop on Linux, when I tried to run "docker-compose up" in my terminal to self host Budibase according to this  [Docker Compose Documentation](https://docs.budibase.com/docs/docker-compose), an error occurred, which results that I am unable to open my Budibase on localhost.

```
Pulling app-service (budibase.docker.scarf.sh/budibase/apps:)...
latest: Pulling from budibase/apps
32820e52a00e: Pull complete
3069e48294bd: Pull complete
6c63e325eb60: Pull complete
4143315d8dc3: Pull complete
eac721e0dfcf: Pull complete
ba9a65d462ff: Pull complete
e38813606086: Pull complete
f1aaf63aa584: Extracting [====================================>              ]  123.1MB/170.7MBBwnload complete
6ab0c616ca87: Download complete
8442d36781b5: Download complete
51f246859303: Download complete
ERROR: Compose tried decoding the following data chunk, but failed:
'copying response body from Docker: unexpected EOF\n'
```

Running with docker-compose version 1.29.0

According to the docker documentation [Docker Compose](https://docs.budibase.com/docs/docker-compose), I should be able to run "docker-compose up" and open my Budibase locally through Localhost, however localhost has refused to connect.

Comment: Please edit your title to accurately summarise your problem. "couldn't run docker-compose up" is not true: you are definitely running it. Running it is resulting in an error (possibly due to a corrupt layer) but you are running it.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677592/docker-pull-unexpected-eof

Comment: Do you have enough free space? Might be that your disk is filling up while extracting?